# How to stop RecyclerView in fragment from pushing down and hiding the BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

My app uses a BottomNavigationBar to switch between three fragments. One of the fragments contain a RecyclerView within a ConstraintLayout. The RecyclerView pushes down the BottomNavigationBar making it invisible and unusable. Here is the xml code:

The main activity with the BottomNavigationView

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationTheme"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment with the RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is how I change the fragments within the fragment container

```
private fun setCurrentFragment(fragment: Fragment) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
            commit()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new in android, so my answer could be wrong.

Replace  layout_height = "match_parent" in your fragment with the recyclerview  to  layout_height = "wrap_content" (Firstly try for recyclerview, then try for the constraintlayout, if not works try to change for both recyclerview and constraintlayout)